# Different results when finding the eigenspace associated with an eigenvalue

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have found 2 eigenvalues $\lambda = 1$ and $\lambda = 5$ for the following matrix: $$A = \left[\begin{matrix} 2 & -3 \\ -1 & 4 \end{matrix}\right]$$

Now, I have successfully found the eigenspace $E_A(5) = \{\left[\begin{matrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \end{matrix}\right]: t \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{matrix} \right], t\in \mathbb{R}\}$

But I am having problems finding the eigenspace associated with $\lambda = 1$, I keep getting a multiple of the vector $\left[ \begin{matrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right]$, but apparently it is not correct according to Maxima

[image]

and I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct.

$(3,1)$ is parallel to $(1,\frac13)$.

Remember that $v$ being an eigenvector implies that $\lambda v$ is also an eigenvector with same eigenvalue, for every $\lambda\ne0$, and the set of their scalar multiples will conincide.

Comment: Exactly, any of them represents the same eigenline (1 dimensional eigenspace).